# How to add jQuery script slider function of html website to php website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My question is about jQuery, PHP and html. I have an html template and I want to convert it into a php website. Inside html template there is a jQuery slider with the following code :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#lightgallery').lightGallery();
  });
</script>
```

This code is not working in my php website and showing error. Without this code, the slider is not showing in the final php website. I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please try writing the code in <script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('#lightgallery').lightGallery(); }); </script> tag

Comment: What error are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

few steps in order to execute above code in your website
1) Make sure you have included the Jquery script in your code
e.g `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2) Add above code in $(document).ready() function. 
this will resolve your issue